# why I see this unclear error?:npm ERR code Unknown system error -122npm ERR

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, next.js, cpanel

I have Next.js project that works on my local machine perfectly, But when I created this application and tried to run npm install on cpanel I received these unclear errors:

```
npm ERR! code Unknown system error -122npm ERR! syscall writenpm ERR! errno -122npm ERR! Unknown system error -122: Unknown system error -122, writenpm ERR! code Unknown system error -122npm ERR! syscall writenpm ERR! errno -122npm ERR! Unknown system error -122: Unknown system error -122, writenpm ERR! code Unknown system error -122npm ERR! syscall writenpm ERR! errno -122npm ERR! Unknown system error -122: Unknown system error -122, writenpm WARN deprecated cli-ux@4.9.3: Package no longer supported. Contact Support at https://www.npmjs.com/support for more info.npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0
```

I changed cli-ux and debug version, but I still see these!

Comment: Do you have admin rights when installing on cpanel ?

Comment: @ErenYeager tnx.I'm checking with my provider .but if I don't have admin rights how I created application?

Comment: You just need to make sure you have root-level roots when installing: https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/general-systems-administration/guide-to-node-js-installations/

It might not be the issue but worth double checking if you are unsure

Comment: @ErenYeager you're right.I don't have root level access!

Comment: Awesome, added it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make sure you have root-level roots when installing

https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/general-systems-administration/guide-to-node-js-installations/